# Running linux mint with only free software?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, free-software

Is it possible to strip down linux mint to only use free software and replace the proprietary software with free software and would doing this even make sense?

Comment: The program `vrms` (Virtual Richard M. Stallman) will tell you about any non-free packages installed.

Comment: Yes, it is called Debian

Comment: Does Linux Mint by default have any unfree software?
There is a lot of unfree software like Chrome, Oracle, MySQL-utilities and VirtualBox-extras you can install, but most of a mainstream Linux distro would be free software.

Comment: @ivanivan I've just tried it on my Mint. Two things are important: 1) I have only 18 non-free package out of 3766 packages. 2) None of them are essential.

Comment: @hschou On my system, different firmware packages use non-free software + skype/viber + rar + most loved nvidia.

Comment: @peterh Oh yes, [Nvidia](https://www.wired.com/2012/06/torvalds-nvidia-linux/). If you want to avoid unfree drivers you have to choose hardware which does not require it. I think my Turris Omnia router is quite free and Raspberry Pi too.

Comment: @hschou Oh, thanks. I don't know if it was a good idea from a political view. I think the problem is that we don't want only Linux drivers, which is mainly a cost question for the nvidia (X money for developing it, Y money from the increased sales, X < Y?), but we want open source drivers. The Linux kernel was intentionally constructed against the closed source drivers (there is no binary API in it). Btw, my experiences with the similarly closed source AMD drivers are worser as with the NVidia. In my opinion, the "closed source driver problem" could be solved only my a government

Comment: @hschou intervention: simply from the law of right over our own property should be interpreted on a way, that a company can sell any hardware if and only if it has an opensource driver. It could handle also the dirty, nasty policies of the apple and microsoft, too (you have to pay for them roughly \$100 for the right to run your own program on your own mobile phone - for a year. After that, you have to pay for that again)

Comment: What essential features of a distro do you need that Mint provides? Perhaps you could find an alternative, 100% free-software distribution that provides these? P.S. It is unlikely that Mint could be 100% free, as that would require use of the Linux-libre kernel (de-blobbed), which might not work with your hardware.